# How do I share a database between an Activity and a ContentProvider?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an Android Activity, and a ContentProvider that (as I understand it) gets instantiated automatically because I've associated it with a search intent in `res/xml/searchable.xml`.

I've also created a SQLiteOpenHelper which I'd like to use from the Activity and the Content provider, but I don't know how to make it accessible to both of them.

- If I create the helper in the Activity's onCreate, I don't know how
  to get a reference to the Activity from the ContentProvider.
- If I instantiate the helper from the ContentProvider's onCreate method, I
  don't know how to get a reference to the ContentProvider instance
  from the Activity.

Which object should own the SQLiteOpenHelper, and how can I access it from the other one?

Comment: if you already have CP use SLOH only in CP and in Activity acces data via CP ...

Comment: But how do I access the ContentProvider instance from the Activity if I don't have a reference to it? This is exactly my problem.

Comment: you will not get instance of CP ... you should just query CP with `Activity.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://your.content"), cols, rest, of, the, stuff);` ....

Comment: Thank you, that works. Would you please add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to global Application object which you will be able to access from `Activity` and `Content Provider`. You can Instantiate `SQLOpenHelper` in either `Activity` or `CP` by just checking if its null or not and if its null create new `SQLOpenHelper` object and assign to global object.

```
public class ClassName extends Application {

    private SQLiteOpenHelper helper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public SQLiteOpenHelper getHelper() {
        return helper;
    }

    public void setHelper(SQLiteOpenHelper helper) {
        this.helper = helper;
    }

}
```

and you have to specify in `AndroidManifest.xml` that you are creating Application context

```
<application
        android:name="ClassName"             // <----- This line
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

then from your `Activity` or `Content Provider` call helper like this.

```
SQLiteOpenHelper helper = ((ClassName)getApplication()).getHelper();

if(null == helper) {
helper = new SQLiteOpenHelper();
}
```

Comment: I don't think [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) has a `getApplication()` method. Am I missing something?

Comment: try using getApplicationContext() instead of getApplication(), does same thing.

Comment: It doesn't have `getApplicationContext()` either.

Answer (score 0):

((ClassName) getContext().getApplicationContext()).getHelper()